# mysql select statement is not working on ubuntu server and is not returning any errors

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to run the following code for selecting some data in mySQL database on my server

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    echo "1";
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT articlecomments.articleCommentID,
                                        articlecomments.comment,
                                        articlecomments.comment_date,
                                        articlecomments.userID,
                                        users.username
                                FROM articlecomments
                                INNER JOIN users ON articlecomments.userID = users.user_id
                                WHERE articlecomments.articleID = ?
                                ORDER BY articlecomments.comment_date ASC");
    echo "2";
    echo $stmt->errno;
    echo $stmt->error;
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $articleID);
    echo "3";
    echo $stmt->errno;
    echo $stmt->error;
    $r = $stmt->execute();
    echo "4";
    echo $stmt->errno;
    echo $stmt->error;
    $stmt->bind_result($message_id, $messageStr, $message_date, $user_id, $username);
    echo "5";
    echo $stmt->errno;
    echo $stmt->error;
    $messages = array ();
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        $message = new Message();
        $message->message_id     = $message_id;
        $message->message        = $messageStr;
        $message->message_date   = $message_date;
        $message->user_id        = $user_id;
        $message->username       = $username;
        array_push($messages, $message);
    }
    echo "6";
    $stmt->close();

    return $messages;
```

The problem is that it downs't return anything from the database when I run it on my ubuntu server, but it does when I run it on localhost.

The echo's is for checking for how long the code runs. And it echo out: 1234.
Which means that my code stops at "bind_result(...)".

It is not printing out any errors.
I have also tried executing my sql statement directly in the database (replacing the ? with 8) and got the correct data back. Which means that all column names etc. are correct.

could it be some php.ini settings that are wrong or am I doing something wrong in my?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: You have to add an `echo` in front of getting the error `echo $stmt->error;`. You might also have to set error reporting with `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` depending on your PHP settings.

Comment: oh right ;) I tried it and got 4 0's (0 errors for 4 of the places where I call errno).
And still no error messages.. even after adding ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

Comment: Are you *sure* you're connecting to the right database? You're not getting confused between a database that's local to your machine, and a database that's on the server, are you?

Comment: No absolutely not.. I have checked that a bunch of times. And it is connection to the right database.

Comment: I confirm, I have the same problem: ubuntu 14, no error messages but no echo after call to "bind_result". Same identical php works on win8.

Comment: I've found out that if I remove the field of type "longblob" from the query, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the real reason (probably a bug should be reported to mysql, at least for the missing warning/error), but I've found out that if you limit the size of the BLOB object, it works.

Probably because of this:

[11.1.3 String Type Overview](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html)

> *A BLOB column with a maximum length of 65,535 (216 – 1) bytes. Each*
> *BLOB value is stored using a 2-byte length prefix that indicates the*
> *number of bytes in the value.*
>
> **An optional length M can be given for this type. If this is done,
> MySQL creates the column as the smallest BLOB type large enough to
> hold values M bytes long.**

And this:

> LONGBLOB
>
> *A BLOB column with a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 or 4GB (232 – 1)*
> *bytes. The effective maximum length of LONGBLOB columns depends on the*
> *configured maximum packet size in the client/server protocol and*
> *available memory. Each LONGBLOB value is stored using a 4-byte length*
> *prefix that indicates the number of bytes in the value.*

there are different behaviours on different OS.

I don't know the data type of your fields but, if you use BLOBS, maybe this could help.
In my case I need to store PDF files not bigger than 400K so setting BLOB(500000) solved my problem.